# Scrapy item pipeline for creating a list and writing to a file at the end of the crawl

Tags: python, list, scope, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm working on a scrapy project in which I'm scraping items assigned which have a date. I have a pipeline function set up to write the items to a file but what I would like to create a separate file for the twenty oldest items scraped, however, I'm running into some difficulties.

The trouble is in getting access to the list of the oldest items that is created within the class. It seems I cannot pass `self` into the `spider_closed` function. It seems to only take one argument- the spider it responds to closing.

Here is what I've tried so far for the pipeline function:

```
class twentyOldest(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # connect to spider_closed signal
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, spider_closed)

        # create list for storing oldest pages dics and values in item
        oldest = [{'lastUpdatedDateTime':datetime.today()}]

        # write table header
        line = "{0:15} {1:40} {2:} \n\n".format("Domain","Last Updated","URL")
        self.oldOutput.write(line)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        if item['group'] == "Old Page":
            itemAge = item['lastUpdatedDateTime']

            currentYoungest = max(x['lastUpdatedDateTime'] for x in self.oldest)

            # if item is older than youngest item in the list, remove that item (if list has more than 20 pages) and add the new one
            if itemAge < currentYoungest:
                if len(self.oldest) > 20:


                       # delete current 'youngest'
                        place = self.oldest.index(max(self.oldest, key=lambda x:x['lastUpdatedDateTime']))
                        del self.oldest[place]

                    # add new item
                    self.oldest.append(item)


            return item

        def spider_closed(SPIDER_NAME):

                # sort the array based on age
                oldest = sorted(oldest, key=lambda k: k['lastUpdatedDateTime']) 

                #open file for writing the list to
                oldOutput = open('twenty_oldest_pages.txt', 'wb')

                # write the dict to the file created
                for item in oldest:
                    line = "{0:15} {1:40} {2:} \n".format(item['domain'],item["lastUpdated"],item["url"])
                oldOutput.write(line)

            return item
```

As mentioned above, the issue happens in the `spider_closed` function because it doesn't have access to the list created in the initialization.

Does anyone know a way around this? I'm relatively new to program and could easily be missing some simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see scrapy documentation [pipeline page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#close_spider), change your `spider_closed` function to:

```
def close_spider(self, spider):
```

also, there is no need to listen to close spider signal, close_spider function will be called by default (by [scrapy middleware manager](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/middleware.py))

using the default close_spider function self should be perfectly accessible.